# customize and style predefined blocks

Tags: drupal-7

I am new in drupal. I want to customize and style my login or my registration form.
There are some predefined blocks in `Admin|Structure|Blocks`. Login form is one of these predefined blocks and I want to show it in a specific region in my `page.tpl.php` page. the following code in `page.tpl.php` shows a login form. I want to style it with bootstrap css. How can I do that?
I have searched a lot and found some code in template.php and so on. But none of them worked. :(
Thank You For Your Help!

```
 <?php  if($page['login_region'])
         print render($page['login_region']); 
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this, just typing html and printing the region, then you can add css with your classes, or you can install [Block Class Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/block_class) to add classes to blocks:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3 customclass"?
    <?php  if($page['login_region'])
      print render($page['login_region']); 
    ?>
  </div>
</div>
```